# capture the second E2ETraceEvent of a svclog file

Tags: c#, xml, trace

I need to find the tag  200  using the service trace viewer, it looks something like that!

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-14799">
<ns2:SendInvoice xmlns:ns2="http://www.zadrwan.com/services/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.zadrwan.com/services/DocumentSendTo" xmlns:ns4="http://www.zadrwan.com/services/VersionRequest">                            
<ns2:Response>200</ns2:Response>
<ns2:Comments>Success!.</ns2:Comments>
</ns2:SendInvoice>
```

when running the webservice does the Trace and writes an E2ETraceEvent the first one I don't need it, but the second one E2ETraceEvent (request) is the one I need and where is the

I found some code on this page [monitoring-and-reading-svclog-file](http://haishibai.blogspot.com/2009/04/monitoring-and-reading-svclog-file.html)

my code is like this:

```
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:

                        if (reader.Name == "E2ETraceEvent")
                        {

                            XmlReader subReader = reader.ReadSubtree();

                            while (subReader.Read())
                            {
                                switch (reader.NodeType)
                                {
                                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                                        while (reader.Name == "Body")
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine(subReader.ReadOuterXml());
                                        } 

                                        break;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
```

how do i catch the second one, with the tag that contains n2 response ??

Comment: Xml you need to get the entire file, otherwise, you will get an exception.  The 200 Done is the results of an http (not xml) and it the final status of an http response.  the code you posted can't work.   You cannot use a XmlReader to get http.

Comment: @jdweng you are right! but in this case I just put a portion of code por explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the namespace.  Something like:

```
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmanager = new XmlNamespaceManager(reader.NameTable);
            nsmanager.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://www.zadrwan.com/services/");

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.Name)
                {
                    case "ns2:Response":
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInnerXml());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```